# WP-API - How get post resource by name instead ID?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a system integration java webapp - wordpress CMS. I adopted the WP-API plugin.

In my case i have some codes in JSPs like.. for example using JSTL:

```
<c:import url="[[host-wordpress]]/wp-api/post/44888">
```

However, if a wordpress user recreate the post consequently broken my integration.
Also would be intuitive for java frontend programmer find a code like :

```
<c:import url="[[host-wordpress]]/wp-api/post/news-about-something">
```

I saw in wp-api documentation that is possible by WP-QUERY, however i would like to implement a less invasive method.

Anybody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I forked wp-api and I added a new method :

https://github.com/dufabricio/WP-API/commit/3c3399c9a613143590d38df06a8f4c4848b21627

I don't know if it is the better way, but this method solves my issue by now :)